# Looping through array based on POST variables - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, post

I've currently got a page that receives form data, I have two pieces of post information -

```
$country_name = $_POST[“country_name”];
$price_point = $_POST[“price_point”];
```

I have a spreadsheet currently that has this information in columns

[image: Information Format]

I need to be able to run a function that uses the post variables and finds the corresponding value from the array.

I haven't created an array yet, as I don't know the best way to format this array. This is where I'm struggling..

Example output would be;

Post value for country is US. 
The price point is 2.
The value would be 1.5.

Major love for anyone that can help me out with the below!

Thanks

Comment: Read up on PHPexcel to read and write to excel sheets. Else you will need to use a database like mysql (and phpmyadmin as gui for mysql) and query it which is the best way to go. With phpexcel you can import an spreadsheet into an array or object, make modifications with php and export it back.

Comment: You will need to use the indexes of the array for the fastest search $arr = array('US'=>[...], 'UK'=>[...]);  or dynamically rearrange the array based on search parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an array like that

```
$dataPoints = array(
    array(
        'point' => 1,
        'price' => 1.5,
        'country' => 'UK'
    ),
    array(
        'point' => 1,
        'price' => 1.3,
        'country' => 'US'
    ),
    array(
        'point' => 1,
        'price' => .8,
        'country' => 'SWEDEN'
    ),
    ...
)
```

And a function like

```
function getPrice($pricePoint, $country) {
    // Search in array for good price
    foreach ($dataPoints as $dataPoint) {
        if ($dataPoint['point'] == $pricePoint && $dataPoint['country'] == $country) {
            return $dataPoint['price'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And call it with your post parameters for print

```
$pp = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price_point');
$country = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'country_name');
$price = getPrice($pp,$country);

echo 'Country is ', $country, '. The price point is ', $pp, '. The price is ', $price;
```

Comment: Camille, this looks like the solution I'm after, how would I search the array based on those points though after I've passed them to getPrice?

Comment: I add body of search function _getPrice_

Answer (score 0):

alternatively i would just put the values in a multidimensional array like my example below

once this spreadsheet get's a lot bigger i would advice to generate the array   from values out of a database.

```
<?php
    $country_name = 'UK';
    $price_point = 4;

    $arr = array(
        'UK' => array(
            1 => 1.5,
            2 => 1.6,
            3 => 1.9,
            4 => 12
        ),
        'US' => array(
            1 => 1.3,
            2 => 1.5,
            3 => 1.6,
            4 => 1.7
        ),
        'SWEDEN' => array(
            1 => 0.8,
            2 => 0.7,
            3 => 0.5,
            4 => 0.3
        )
    );

    $value = $arr[$country_name][$price_point];
    echo $value;
    // echoes 12
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question. As stated in the question _"I need to be able to run a function that uses the post variables"_ You should edit the answer to include such function